# Specific formatting for chapter heading and definition

Tags: tcolorbox, titlesec, spanish

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[head=15pt, top=2in, bottom=2in, left=1.5in, right=1in,  footskip=2.5cm, % footskip margin
        ]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[c]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[l]{OPOSICIONES}
\fancyfoot[r]{Azahara Carpintero}
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\Large\filleft\bfseries}                    % format applied to label+text
{}                                                      % label
{1pc}                                                   % horizontal separation between label and title body
{%
    % draw a box around the chapter number
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
            enhanced,flushright upper,
            boxrule=1.4pt,
            colback=white,colframe=black!50!yellow,
            drop fuzzy midday shadow=black!50!yellow,
        width=2.8cm]
        \resizebox{2cm}{!}{\color{gray!80}\thechapter}%
    \end{tcolorbox}\Huge} % before the title body
[] 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,etoolbox}
\newtheoremstyle{custom}% name
    {}% Space above
    {}% Space below
    {}% Body font
    {}% Indent amount
    {\bfseries}% Theorem head font
    {}% Punctuation after theorem head
    {\newline}% Space after theorem head
    {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{#2}{\mdseries\thmnote{ [#3]}}}% Theorem head spec(can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)
\theoremstyle{custom}
\swapnumbers
 \newtheorem{theo}{\quad Teorema}[section]
    \newenvironment{theorem}
      {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\square$}\theorem}
      {\popQED\endtheorem}
\newtheorem*{demostracion}{Demostración}
\newtheorem{definition}{\quad Definición}[section]
\newtheorem{pro}{\quad Proposición}[section]
\newtheorem{obs}{\quad Observación}[section]
\newtheorem{cro}{\quad Corolario}[section]
\newtheorem{nota}{\quad Notación}[section]

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\chapter{Homotecia y semejanza en el plano}
\section{Introducción}
En el tema 37 del presente temario (Relación de semejanza en el plano) se veían los polígonos semejantes, que eran aquéllos en que se establecía una
correspondencia entres sus vértices, de forma que las distancias entre los vértices de un polígono y los correspondientes del otro son proporcionales. 

La generalización de esto es la introducción de aplicaciones del plano en sí mismo, tales que la distancia entre las imágenes de dos puntos es proporcional a la distancia entre dichos puntos. Éstas son las semejanzas del plano.

Comenzaremos con un tipo particular de las mismas, que serán las homotecias, que transforman rectas en rectas paralelas, manteniendo un punto fijo.
\section{Homotecias del plano}
\begin{definition}
\textit{Sea $H: E \rightarrow E$ una aplicación y sea $O \in E$. Se dice que $H$ es una homotecia de centro $O$ si $H(O)=O$ y $\forall r \subset E$ recta: $H(r)$ es una recta paralela a $r$.}
\end{definition}

\begin{pro}
Sean $O \in E$ y $H: E \rightarrow E$ una homotecia de centro $O$. Sea $r \subset E$ recta con $O \in r$. Entonces $H(r)=r$
\end{pro}
\begin{demostracion}
 $H(r)$ es la única paralela a $r$ conteniendo a $H(O)$. Pero $H(O)=O$, luego $H(r)$ es la única paralela a $r$ que contiene a $O$ , es decir, la propia $r$.
\end{demostracion}
\begin{pro}
 Sean $O, A, A^{\prime} \in E$ con $A^{\prime} \in O A-\{O\}$ (recta definida por $O$ y $A$, excluido $O$). Entonces $\exists \mid H: E \rightarrow E$ homotecia con centro $O$ y $H(A)=A^{\prime}$.    
\end{pro}
\begin{demostracion}

  Sea $P$ punto cualquiera del plano $y$ elegimos un punto $X$ que no se encuentre ni en la recta $O A$ ni en $OP$. Se trazan las rectas $O A$ (que por hipótesis contiene a $A^{\prime}$ ), $OX, OP, AX$ y $X P$.

Se traza la recta que, conteniendo a $A^{\prime}$ es paralela a $A X$, la cual corta a $OX$ en $X^{\prime}$.

Por $X^{\prime}$ se traza una paralela a $PX$, la cual corta a $OP$ en $P^{\prime}$.

Sea $H: E \rightarrow E$ homotecia con centro en $O$ y con $H(A)=A^{\prime}$.

Entonces $H(A X) \mid A X$ y $A^{\prime}=H(A) \in H(A X) \Rightarrow H(A X)=A^{\prime} X^{\prime}$.

$X \in A X\Rightarrow H(X) \in H(A X)=A^{\prime} X^{\prime}$

Como $O \in OX$, por la proposición $2.1: H(O X)=O X$ 

$X \in O X \Rightarrow {H}({X}) \in {H}(O X)=O X=O X^\prime$

Así pues $H(X) \in A^{\prime} X^{\prime} \cap O X^{\prime} \Rightarrow H(X)=X^{\prime}$.

De análoga manera, utilizando la recta $P X$ se concluye que $H(P)=P^{\prime}$. 

De ahí la unicidad.

Falta ver que la aplicación antes descrita es una homotecia de centro $O$ con $ H(A)=A^{\prime}:$

Veamos en primer lugar que el punto $P^{\prime}$ obtenido es independiente de la elección del punto $X$ :

Por el teorema fundamental de semejanza de triángulos (ver tema 37 , proposición 2.1) se tiene que $OAX \sim OA'X'$ y $OPX \sim OP'X'$

Entonces: $\frac{O P^{\prime}}{O P}=\frac{O X^{\prime}}{O X}=\frac{O A^{\prime}}{O A}$, luego $O P^{\prime}=O P \cdot \frac{O A^{\prime}}{O A}$, con lo que el punto $P^{\prime}$ sólo depende de $O, A, P$ y $A^{\prime}$.
\end{demostracion}

 

\end{document}
```

[[image: I want chapter heading as shown in figure and the style as in another image only definition ][1]]

Comment: What's your question? Please be specific.

Comment: I just want CAPTIULO  on the top of chapter number

Comment: Off-topic: You should load `newtxmath` and `newtxtext` after, not before, `amsmath` and `amssymb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you insert either

```
{\huge\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}} % all-uppercase
```

or

```
{\huge\textsc{\chaptername}}  % small-caps
```

at the start of the final argument of the `\titleformat{\chapter}` directive. If `\huge` isn't the right size, do choose a sizing directive that better fits the intended "look".

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{%amsfonts, % amsfonts is loaded automatically by amssymb
            amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,etoolbox}

\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext} % load these packages after, not before, amsmath and amssymb

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[head=15pt, vmargin=2in, left=1.5in, right=1in,  
            footskip=2.5cm, % footskip margin
           ]{geometry}
   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[c]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[l]{OPOSICIONES}
\fancyfoot[r]{Azahara Carpintero}

\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\Large\filleft\bfseries} % format applied to label+text
{}                                   % label
{1pc}                                % horizontal separation between label and title body
{%
{\huge\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}}   % <-- new
    % draw a box around the chapter number:
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
            enhanced,flushright upper,
            boxrule=1.4pt,
            colback=white,colframe=black!50!yellow,
            drop fuzzy midday shadow=black!50!yellow,
        width=2.8cm]
        \resizebox{2cm}{!}{\color{gray!80}\thechapter}%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
    %\Huge % <-- has no effect
    } % before the title body
[] 

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nameref}

\newtheoremstyle{custom}% name
    {}% Space above
    {}% Space below
    {}% Body font % <-- are you sure you don't want "\itshape"?
    {}% Indent amount
    {\bfseries}% Theorem head font
    {}% Punctuation after theorem head
    {\newline}% Space after theorem head
    {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{#2}{\mdseries\thmnote{ [#3]}}}% Theorem head spec(can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)
    
\theoremstyle{custom}
\swapnumbers
\newtheorem{theo}{\quad Teorema}[section]
    \newenvironment{theorem}
      {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\square$}\theorem}
      {\popQED\endtheorem}
%\newtheorem*{demostracion}{Demostración}

\newtheorem{definition}{\quad Definición}[section]
\newtheorem{pro}{\quad Proposición}[section]
\newtheorem{obs}{\quad Observación}[section]
\newtheorem{cro}{\quad Corolario}[section]
\newtheorem{nota}{\quad Notación}[section]

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

%\usepackage{tgpagella} % ??
%\usepackage{mdframed}  % ??

\begin{document}

\onehalfspacing

\chapter{Homotecia y semejanza en el plano}
\section{Introducción}

En el tema 37 del presente temario (Relación de semejanza en el plano) se veían los polígonos semejantes, que eran aquéllos en que se establecía una
correspondencia entres sus vértices, de forma que las distancias entre los vértices de un polígono y los correspondientes del otro son proporcionales. 

La generalización de esto es la introducción de aplicaciones del plano en sí mismo, tales que la distancia entre las imágenes de dos puntos es proporcional a la distancia entre dichos puntos. Éstas son las semejanzas del plano.

Comenzaremos con un tipo particular de las mismas, que serán las homotecias, que transforman rectas en rectas paralelas, manteniendo un punto fijo.


\section{Homotecias del plano}

\begin{definition}
\textit{Sea $H\colon E \rightarrow E$ una aplicación y sea $O \in E$. Se dice que $H$ es una homotecia de centro $O$ si $H(O)=O$ y $\forall r \subset E$ recta: $H(r)$ es una recta paralela a $r$.}
\end{definition}

\begin{pro}
Sean $O \in E$ y $H\colon E \rightarrow E$ una homotecia de centro $O$. Sea $r \subset E$ recta con $O \in r$. Entonces $H(r)=r$
\end{pro}

\begin{proof}
$H(r)$ es la única paralela a $r$ conteniendo a $H(O)$. Pero $H(O)=O$, luego $H(r)$ es la única paralela a $r$ que contiene a $O$, es decir, la propia $r$.
\end{proof}

\begin{pro}
Sean $O$, $A$, $A' \in E$ con $A' \in O A-\{O\}$ (recta definida por $O$ y $A$, excluido $O$). Entonces $\exists \mid H\colon E \rightarrow E$ homotecia con centro $O$ y $H(A)=A'$.    
\end{pro}

\begin{proof}
Sea $P$ punto cualquiera del plano $y$ elegimos un punto $X$ que no se encuentre ni en la recta $O A$ ni en $OP$. Se trazan las rectas $O A$ (que por hipótesis contiene a $A'$), $OX$, $OP$, $AX$ y $X P$.

Se traza la recta que, conteniendo a $A'$ es paralela a $A X$, la cual corta a $OX$ en $X'$.

Por $X'$ se traza una paralela a $PX$, la cual corta a $OP$ en $P'$.

Sea $H\colon E \rightarrow E$ homotecia con centro en $O$ y con $H(A)=A'$.

Entonces $H(A X) \mid A X$ y $A'=H(A) \in H(AX) \Rightarrow H(AX)=A'X'$.

$X \in AX\Rightarrow H(X) \in H(AX)=A'X'$

Como $O \in OX$, por la proposición $2.1\colon H(O X)=O X$ 

$X \in O X \Rightarrow {H}({X}) \in {H}(OX)=OX=O X^\prime$

Así pues $H(X)\in A'X' \cap OX' \Rightarrow H(X)=X'$.

De análoga manera, utilizando la recta $P X$ se concluye que $H(P)=P'$. 

De ahí la unicidad.

Falta ver que la aplicación antes descrita es una homotecia de centro $O$ con $ H(A)=A'$:

Veamos en primer lugar que el punto $P'$ obtenido es independiente de la elección del punto $X$:

Por el teorema fundamental de semejanza de triángulos (ver tema 37, proposición 2.1) se tiene que $OAX \sim OA'X'$ y $OPX \sim OP'X'$.

Entonces: $\frac{OP'}{OP}=\frac{OX'}{O X}=\frac{OA'}{OA}$, luego $OP'=O P \cdot \frac{OA'}{OA}$, con lo que el punto $P'$ sólo depende de $O$, $A$, $P$ y $A'$.

\end{proof}

\end{document}
```